# Picking up JSON object on using client side script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

I am learning WCF and have managed to return a JSON object from my local WCF server.

```
         var service = new GHSAjaxWCFService.GHSService();
         service.DoWork(OnSuccess, null, null);
```

So it get consumed and the result appears in OnSuccess here

```
         function OnSuccess(data) {
         console.log(data);
         }
```

So I am now just trying to get the JSON name/value pairs returned so that I can access them outside the OnSuccess method. Something like this.

```
         var myRes = service.DoWork(OnSuccess, null, null);
```

so then I can directly get at myRes. This doesn't work as I am passing loads of over inner workings. All I need is the JSON result. Can anyone advise me here.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to make use of the response data from *inside* the `OnSuccess()` method. That's the nature of asynchronous APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this thing:

```
   var myRes;
   function OnSuccess(data) {
     console.log(data);
      myRes=data;
     }
```

Now use this variable myRes, try this thing if it helps to you.